# Translation of "client area" (in a web context)

Tags: перевод, одним-словом, информатика

What is the proper translations of **client area**, in a web context?

Google translate gives me:  **клиентская область**.

- Is this correct?
- Can **область** be used for a non-geographical area?

Translating **area** alone, Google translate gives several possibilities:
**площадь**, **область**, **район**, **зона**, **сфера**, **участок**.

- Is **зона** more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several terms.

- **Личный кабинет**. This is used in the context of internet service providers, internet storage providers, hosting services, cellular providers, web money and other billing services. Here, the user can choose subscription services and request the details of recent transactions.
- **Моя анкета**. This is used in the context of various dating services and social networks to set up what data you want others to see on your personal page, such as your interests, age, sex, sexual preferences, location and dating aims.
- **Мой профиль**. This is used on various sites, forums, social networks to set up your preferences. This includes the theme in which the site is displayed for you, your e-mail, your default e-mail notification choices, your age and occupation, timezone etc. This data may or may not be available to other users.
- **Платная зона**. This may be used in the context of porn sites to denote content accessible only to paid accounts.

Answer (score 5):

In the web context, especially if it's something that requires the client to sign in to access the area, I've seen the expressions Личный кабинет and Кабинет пользователя (the second expression appears to be more rare).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what is meant by *client area*.

If it is a part of your site dedicated to clients as opposed to that dedicated to other audiences (such as contractors, or investors, or staff), a dative such as

- *клиентам*
- or *покупателям*

may be used. For example, [rzd.ru](http://www.rzd.ru) uses that convention.

I don't know if that's considered good style in web design, though.

Answer (score 1):

Client area, as it relates to the part of the window used by the client application as opposed to the browser itself, "рабочая площадь."

Answer (score 0):

Напишите "**Для клиентов**" - это будет более литературный перевод.