# How to translate "Admin area" into Russian (web context)

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

Can i ask you what is the proper translation of **ADMIN AREA** in a web context?

Google translate give me this translation: **площадь Админ**

But you know, is much better to ask to Stack Overflow in order to be sure!

Thank you!

Comment: In this case it is necessary to check the phrase in "" (full compliance): "Раздел администратора" - 7010, "админ панель" (including админ-панель etc) - 14,400,000

Comment: "панель администратора" - 83,300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually use the word “админка”, but it slang. Also used: “панель администрирования” and “панель администратора”.

I would use: “админ-панель” (maybe someone will say that it is also slang).

Comment: ya, панель администратора is very nice definition

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing "площадь админ" in Russian. Also, the word admin in Russian is considered a little bit slangy being a short of administrator. If you want to create some button for admin's login it is probably better just  to write "АДМИН", but if you want some words without any slangy hue - use one of these:

"Раздел администратора"

"Отдел администратора"

"Область полномочий администратора"

It is very useful to inform us about usage context of the the phrase, cause sometimes we have special definitions for different things.

Comment: Following the analogy that [has already been discussed](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/how-to-translate-client-area-in-russian-web-context) one might be inclined to opt for "Кабинет администратора".

Comment: @mustaccio I personally like "кабинет администратора" less than provided variant, in my opinion it is heard as real place and not internet site, but probably it is still acceptable variant.

Comment: I'm entirely sure, but wouldn't Раздел/панель администрации/администрирования be better than Раздел администратора ? You know, referring to the *action* performed in that section of website, not to the type of person.

Answer (score 2):

**Раздел администратора** would be most universal, but in web context you may use:

**Администрирование** - a page or link to page with administrator UI. This is simple way to say it.

**Кабинет администратора** - a subdomain or webpage with administrator UI. This is often used instead of *Панель администрирования* on governmental and b2b russian sites.

Answer (score 1):

вход администратора = Admin Login

Not exactly the area, but leads to the area.

Answer (score 0):

Actual russian sites that I have seen use these:

1. Панель управления
2. Центр управления
3. Настройки

Answer (score 0):

In Russian, the best option would be to use the "Администрирование" in the answers above, you are advised to use the option "админка". This expression is used among webmasters, however, to administer the site sometimes attract special employees, for which the expression "админка" looks unusual. Use expressions

1. Панель администратора
2. Администрирование